# Approaches for Game Developement in iphone

Tags: iphone

I am new for game developement and need to know the different approaches to develope a 2D and 3D games in iphone.And which one is the best approach. I am having brief knowledge of cocos2d but don't know about different other alternative approaches that might be helpful. It would be gr8 help if someone might give information about all the approaches available and which are preferable approaches. 
Thanks in advance :)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iphone Game Development](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/913352/iphone-game-development)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you looked at any of the existing questions and answers?  (https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=iphone+game-development)

Irrespective, [What are prime commercial choices for iPhone game development kits/platforms?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/945618/what-are-prime-commercial-choices-for-iphone-game-development-kits-platforms) and perhaps [learning iphone game development](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/720901/learning-iphone-game-development) seems like they should cover what you're asking.